# BlenderGis get SRTM

Tags: add-on

I'm running Blender 2.80 and I installed the latest BlenderGis download.  I am following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj7Z1P2hUWk) to download data and it works MOSTLY.  I can download a basic map, download OSM building data, etc..   but whenever I try to get SRTM elevation data, I get the error:  "Cannot Reach Open Topography Web service, check logs for more info"

1-  How the heck do you check the logs?
2- anyone ran into this error before?  Any ideas.  I couldn't find anything when googling.

Comment: You can reach the console by going to Window (top left corner) > Toggle System Console. Please update with what the error is. You may also have a common problem, did you check the github troubleshooting section ? https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues or https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/268 this seems to be the same issue. You may have to disable filmic-blender ?

Comment: @Gorgious It happens at the same time but unfortunately I am still confused.  Filmic blender is an add-on correct?  i don't believe I ever installed that.  If its not an add on, how do I turn it off?
Also, when I open the system console the way you suggest, nothing ever changes.  It just says "building mosaic" the whole time.  I can send you screenshot if you need

Comment: @Gorgious Edit.  Got the log to show stuff finally, error was: ERROR:BlenderGIS-master.operators.io_get_srtm:112:Http request fails url:http://opentopo.sdsc.edu/otr/getdem?demtype=SRTMGL3&west=-71.44609179665251&east=-71.3651874989&south=41.7938880985195&north=41.830642001628284&outputFormat=GTiff, code:403, error:Forbidden      Annnnd I just figured it out.  My internet firewall is blocking that website

Comment: As simple as that ! Would you mind adding it as an answer and mark it as accepted so that other people can see it too if they stumble upon the same error ?

Answer (score 1):

Log showed this error:
ERROR:BlenderGIS-master.operators.io_get_srtm:112:Http request fails url:opentopo.sdsc.edu/otr/…, code:403, error:Forbidden

Turns out my company firewall was blocking the open topographry website, when i connected to my phone as hotspot it worked great.